# jQuery - Technics for reduce code in on scroll function

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

i have often Code like this and i think there is for sure a way to write it shorter. I would be glad to learn some new technic if there is one =)

please remind it´s inside an on scroll function. Each block is for one layer that is scrolled sideways.

st   : is the actuel scrollTop()
cat3 : scrollTop of content before 3*wh in this case
cat4 : scrollTop of content before + width of cat3
cat5 : scrollTop of content before + width of layer1 + width of cat4
...

```
var w3 = st - (3 * wh);
if (w3 > 0) {
    $('#cat3 .inside').css({
        "left" : -1 * w3 + "px",
        "position" : "fixed"
    });
} else if (w3 < 0){
    $('#cat3 .inside').css({
        "left" : "0",
        "position" : "absolute"
    });
}

var w4 = st - (3 * wh + fh[3]);
if (w4 > 0) {
    $('#cat4 .inside').css({
        "left" : -1 * w4 + "px",
        "position" : "fixed"
    });
} else if (w4 < 0){
    $('#cat4 .inside').css({
        "left" : "0",
        "position" : "absolute"
    });
}

var w5 = st - (3 * wh + fh[3] + fh[4]);
if (w5 > 0) {
    $('#cat5 .inside').css({
        "left" : -1 * w5 + "px",
        "position" : "fixed"
    });
} else if (w5 < 0){
    $('#cat5 .inside').css({
        "left" : "0",
        "position" : "absolute"
    });
}
```

Thank you for your advices!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps wrap the repetitive code in a function:

```
function setScroll(value, selector) {
  var element = $(selector + ' .inside');
  var left, position;

  if (value > 0) {
    left = -1 * value + "px";
    position = 'fixed';
  } else if (value < 0){
    left = 0;
    position = 'absolute';
  }

  element.css({left, position});
}

var w3 = st - (3 * wh);
var w4 = st - (3 * wh + fh[3]);
var w5 = st - (3 * wh + fh[3] + fh[4]);

setScroll(w3, '#cat3');
setScroll(w4, '#cat4');
setScroll(w5, '#cat5');
```

`element.css({left, position});` is ES6 syntax, if for whatever reason you can't use ES6, replace this line with:

```
element.css({
  left: left,
  position: position
});
```

The trick is to identify which parts change, and which parts do not. I identified only two things change here: The value you're comparing with 0, and the element you're modifying.

Comment: Thats great, i will use function that way more now, thank you

Comment: If this is the solution you've decided to go with please mark this answer as accepted by using the check mark :)

Comment: i see no problem with ES6, are there browser who don´t understand it?

Comment: could be the part after the funcion in some sort of a each function? lets think heavy, we would have cat3 - cat100 =)

Comment: IE11 will not support shorthand properties, and a bunch of other ES6 features. Yes if you had even more of these, storing them in an array and using a loop does make sense.

Answer (score 0):

here is my each function. now its total felxible in amount of cats.
f is calculated once outside of the onScroll function. Any suggestions to this? Thanks.

```
    $('.side-scroll').each(function() {
    c[n] = st - (f[n]);
    setScroll(c[n], '#cat' + n);
    n++;
    if(n == ss ){n = 0;}
});
```